# Rails 3: jQuery.get is receiving html response instead of js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got one action called `action_1`. When an user enters `/action_1`, an html response follows. However, I also have a `jQuery.get('/action_1')` call, which should receive a js response. I've got an `action_1.js.erb` file, but somehow, the response I get is in html. I've got the following respond_to block in my action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :layout => false }
end
```

What is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was going on: `jQuery.get()` expects an html response by default. Rails will answer the call with a `html.erb` file when nothing is specified in the action, and also when giving the two options I posted (`format.html` and `format.js`). It will respond with a `js.erb` if nothing is specified and no `html.erb` is found, and when it is specified that it should respond with `format.js` and not `format.html`. In any case, `jQuery.getJSON` expects a json by default (and does not run any javascript) and `jQuery.getScript()` excutes the javascript code

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
jQuery.getJSON('/action_1')
```

so it requests `application/json` instead of `text/html`

Comment: I get the response, but it doesn't execute the javascript in it. For example, if I receive an alert('something'); no alert popup will show up

Comment: For that to happen you need to supply the response as an argument to `eval();`. Be aware though, that this will enable arbitrary code execution. So be sure to use an https connection to verify that the answering server is really yours.

Comment: I don't get it. Shouldn't my js response be rendered by default? If I copy and paste the action_1 action code into an action_2 and then create view action_2.js.erb and call jQuery.get('/action_2'); everything goes according to plan. I understand eval() may work for me, but I've used jQuery.get() many times in my app, and never had this problem before